# How do I get AD user when using ASP.Net Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis, asp.net-identity, windows-authentication

I am trying to get details of current windows (AD) user in my `mvc 5 asp.net` vb.net intranet site.

When I started this project, I set my authentication to individual accounts assuming that I can still get windows user information. But I have had no luck. I can get this information when I am using visual studio in debugging. But this information is replaced by the identity name of apppool in `IIS`.

My intranet site is currently set to use the following config.

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>      
        <!--<deny users="?"/>-->
</authorization>
```

My application is set to use anonymous and windows authentication. If I turn off anonymous, I start getting `query string too long`. It starts going in infinite loop when trying to create a return url. This is really annoying.

Anyways. For me, the concept was: If the user is windows AD user, they can get to my log in page and if correct credentials they can use the site else get kicked out. So a bit like a two factor authentication.

I have settled for allowing anonymous in favour of getting ad information and then based on that I can either deny or allow access. I intend to put this information in my login controller where `signinstatus.success = true`.

I have scoured the internet in trying to find a decent enough solution to try and get this hybrid to work but I am struggling for clarity. In some cases people just want to plug their own tools.

Comment: This might help a bit: http://tech.trailmax.info/2016/03/using-owin-and-active-directory-to-authenticate-users-in-asp-net-mvc-5-application/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AllowAnonymous is necessary when you have a precursor to authorization, i.e. a login page the user must submit. If you don't allow anonymous users to access this page, then there's no way for them to actually login to become authorized to view the page (hence your infinite redirect).

ASP.NET Identity and Windows Auth are distinct and incompatible authorization schemes. You cannot use both simultaneously in the same application. You *can* however, use ASP.NET Identity and add a custom authentication/authorization layer that utilizes an LDAP connection to check credentials against AD. In other words, if you want to use AD, you have to add a manual integration of that.

Comment: Ok. That's quite definitive and I agree with you so thank you very much. But my problem is that in debugging I see my name as Windows logged in user but when I publish my site to iis, it shows me the app pool identity as the username. I would like to know how I can fetch who the ad user is. Many thanks for your help

Comment: Would it work if I allowed anonymous to log in page only and made all others windows authentication? Would it allow me to see the correct windows user then or would it still show app pool identity? 
Regards, 
Waqar

Comment: No. If you use Windows auth, you can't have a separate login. If you want that, you have to go straight Identity and the add a layer to communicate back to AD manually.

Comment: Again definitive. So thanks. What about not being able to see the current ad user.

Comment: @waqar_lionheart Current AD user is impossible without being logged in with AD. If you use Anonymous scheme - you will see a user that is running your website on IIS. This is why you see your name when you run locally - your IIS (Express) is running under your account. And this does not work when you publish it.

Comment: @waqar_lionheart: Essentially, the way the Identity approach would work is that your "user" will always be the user from Identity. The AD connection is there merely for the authentication/authorization. When it comes time to login the user, you verify the credentials against AD rather than the Identity verification. Then, if it's correct you log in the Identity user. You basically have to mirror your AD users in your app, so there's a little bit of duplication. However, the Identity user can basically just be a shell (the bare minimum to simply have a user account in Identity).